# how to change background color using combo boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, background-color

How to change the background of web page using the Combo Boxes in html ? . That is by using the values of combo boxes how to change the color of background in a webpage.

Comment: Have you attempted anything on your own? Is there a specific problem you're struggling with? As it stands, this is too broad of a question to answer.

Comment: Break this down into smaller parts...how to listen for the change...and how to change background using javascript. Then combine the parts togethter

Comment: I have got the solution now. Thanks for your contro.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
RED: <select id=r>
         <script language="javascript">
             for(var i=0;i<=255;i++)
          { 
            document.write("<option>"+i+"</option>");
          }
         </script>
     </select>

GREEN: <select id=g>
         <script language="javascript">
             for(var i=0;i<=255;i++)
          { 
            document.write("<option>"+i+"</option>");
          }
         </script>
    </select>

BLUE: <select id=b>
        <script language="javascript">
             for(var i=0;i<=255;i++)
          { 
            document.write("<option>"+i+"</option>");
          }
         </script>
     </select>
<input type=button onclick=fun() value=Change>

 <script>
function fun()
{
 var x=r.value
 var y=g.value
 var z=b.value

document.body.style.background="rgb("+x+","+y+","+z+")";
}
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```